# removing extra character from json string and handling none data type Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary, key-value

I am trying to remove "s:" from a json string. I am seeing error when i try to strip the extra character from the key value pairs please help.

Code:

```
data = "{
   "attributeInfo":[
      {
         "AttributeName":"s:Density",
         "Weight":"s:0.2",
         "Preference":"s:Closer to a target is better",
         "IdealValue":"s:7850"
      },
      {
         "AttributeName":"s:Endurance Strength",
         "Weight":"s:0.2",
         "Preference":"s:Larger is better",
         "IdealValue":null
      },
      {
         "AttributeName":"s:Modulus of Elasticity",
         "Weight":"s:0.2",
         "Preference":"s:Larger is better",
         "IdealValue":null
      },
      {
         "AttributeName":"s:Cost",
         "Weight":"s:0.2",
         "Preference":"s:Smaller is better",
         "IdealValue":null
      }
]}"
tmp =[]
li = data['attributeInfo']
for j in range(len(li)):
    dict = li[j]
    nDict = {key.strip('s:'): value.strip('s:') for key, value in dict.items()}
    tmp.append(nDict)
print(nDict)
```

Error:
nDict = {key.strip('s:'): value.strip('s:') for key, value in dict.items()}
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

please let me know how i can handle this error, this is due to the presence of null value in some of the values.

Answer (score 0):

if your `data` variable is a JSON valid value, you can parse it by using the `json` module of Python.

Your error comes from the `null` value present in the `IdealValue` key.

`nDict = {key.strip('s:'): value.strip('s:') for key, value in dict.items() if value is not None}` should do the trick but won't have the `IdealValue` in the resulting dict if its value was `null`

Best,